# Add wpf ListView Group?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I have created `listview` and added columns through `vb.net` code.

Here is my code:

**XMAL Code**

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="LV1" />
```

**VB.Net Code**

```
    'Create Grid View & Add Columns to Grid View 
    Dim GV1 As New GridView
    GV1.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Inv. No.", .Width = 100, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("No2")})
    GV1.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Party", .Width = 200, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("GLDisplay")})
    GV1.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Broker", .Width = 100, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Br")})
    GV1.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Inv. Value", .Width = 100, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Total")})
    GV1.Columns.Add(New GridViewColumn With {.Header = "Outstanding", .Width = 100, .DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("Os")})

    'Set Date Formatting on Required Columns
    GV1.Columns(3).DisplayMemberBinding.StringFormat = "#0.00"
    GV1.Columns(4).DisplayMemberBinding.StringFormat = "#0.00"

    LV1.View = GV1 : LV1.ItemsSource = DT1.DefaultView
```

Now I want to add Groups to this `listview`

Something like this (Only Grouping Part)
[Click Here to View Image](http://www.componentone.com/newimages/Products/Screenshots/StudioWPF/C1FlexGrid/FlexGrid_itunes.png)